Is it true that before modern Europe, there were no "nations"?
The concepts of "nation", "state", "nation-state" and "country" are not self obvious.
Here are definitions:

State


A State is an independent, sovereign government exercising control over a certain spatially defined and bounded area, whose borders are usually clearly defined and internationally recognized by other states.


Nation


A nation is a group of people who see themselves as a cohesive and coherent unit based on shared cultural or historical criteria.


In Latin, natio represents the children of the same birth and also a human group of same origin.[11] By Cicero, natio is used for "people".[12]


Nation-state


A Nation-State is the idea of a homogenous nation governed by its own sovereign state—where each state contains one nation. This idea is almost never achieved.


Country

I would say "country" refers intuitively to "nation-state".
Some authors point that "nation" is a social construct. Below (MacDonald 1989) is an example (the author uses "nation" as meaning "country"):

Nations are units of identity and organization which found their modern form in the last two hundred years or so of European thought. They are creations. This applies as much to the relatively well-established nations of Europe as it does to those areas of the world to which Europe's ideas of nationhood have been exported more recently. Nations are not natural and self-generating units, or the emergence or re-emergence of atavistic forces of blood, soul, or territory.

But I have most difficulties in believing that the local "peoples" did not in some way or another identify with the Kingdom or Empire which ruled their territory. In Ancient China, the commoners could pass Imperial Exams to become civil servants of the Empire. In Muslim Califates, commoners could become Muslim to pay lesser taxes and fight for the Califate. In France and Japan, in some periods, commoners could become Knights and fight for the Kingdom.
If I am not mistaken, the legitimacy of the Kingdom came from protecting the population from "outgroup" invaders.
In addition, peoples of a same territory and as ruled by an Empire or Kingdom used to speak dialects which were related. This is the case of the French "occitan" language and "langue d'oïl". In China, the guanhua language with its varities (Northeastern, Beijing, Ji–Lu, Jiao–Liao, Lower Yangtze, Central Plains, Lan–Yin, Southwestern) is to be found all over the territory. Both these French and Chinese had to see with the language of the ruler (Romans and Franks conquerors, and the capitals of successive Chinese dynasties often situated on the North, from where originates the guanhua).
If really there was no ethnolinguistic or and/contractual connection between the ruling elite and the "people", then I would say the people simply experienced that they were under the ruling of outgroup invaders and conquerors, and therefore somehow formed themselves an independent "nation" in the etymological sense. And this certainly presented a fragility for the governing power.
Finally, as a point of fact, "nation" (in the sense of MacDonalds, i.e. more or less ethno-linguistically unified "country") emerge when the different peoples under a common ruling entity start to speak the same language and share the same culture, as is what happened gradually over decades if not centuries in France with the rise of capitalism, the print, a centralized bureaucracy, etc.
It arrived at an accelerated pace in Italy, Germany and all over Europe, but this was not the result of a political ingenuity even less intellectual "social construction", on the contrary, these were popular uprisings. The nationalist sentiment emerged in China from the European imperialistic threat, and this as much elite movements as popular movements.
And indeed, Moffett (2019) argues that modern nation states are, sociologically, in no way different from ancestral hunter-gather societies, and chiefdoms, and that national identity "bind people with a mental force no less valid and real than the physical force that binds atoms to molecules, turning them into concrete realities."
References:
McDonald, M. (1989). “We are not French!”: Language, Culture and Identity in Brittany. London and New York: Routledge.
Moffett, M. W. (2019). The human swarm: How our societies arise, thrive, and fall. Hachette UK.

I'm flagging as not-philosophy, since I feel this would be a better question for history, politics, or skeptics.

Any sufficiently precise definition capturing the full nuance of any modern word refers exclusively to modern concepts because languages change constantly and always reflect the spirit and context of the time of their use. There is no cause for a leap from this fact about the way language works in relation to abstractions to idea that there was no similar thing to the thing that we call a nation, which has continuity with that thing, and which may even have been called by that name.

Are we sure the author means nation as country as sovereign state as ethno-territorial-governmental unit? That would be a very odd definition in a world where Ireland and the USSR were in the news every day.

The modern idea of the nation-state began with the Treaty of Westphalia in 1648.

What about all the folks who refer to "First Nations"? The usage absolutely fits your definition of: "a group of people who see themselves as a cohesive and coherent unit based on shared cultural or historical criteria".

Concerning the concept and term “nation” SEP provides two definitions

a nation is any group of people aspiring to a common political
state-like organization

the classic ethno-nation is a community of
origin and culture, including prominently a language and customs.


To provide an answer to the question in your title I take the second definition, because it is nearest to your own definition

“A nation is a group of people who see themselves as a cohesive and
coherent unit based on shared cultural or historical criteria.”


According to the second definition, at the beginning of the Roman
republic at about 500 BCE the Romans considered themselves a nation,
as opposed to the nation of the Etruscans and also the Greek nation.
At least at a later time in the eyes of Vergil and his national
epos “Aeneid”.
This example shows already that the concept of a nation is much
older than modern Europe.

Possibly also the Jewish people at the time of king David considered
themselves to be a nation, opposed to the indigeneous people in
Palestine and the Great Powers around.
Hence the concept of a nation
does not seem to be a European concept at all.



So, First Nations people get the prize for being first, yes?

@ScottRowe - First Nations means the first nations of the continent, not so much the first nations of the world. By most standards, I would suspect that first nations in the world arose in Africa in prehistory.

@JoWehler - With respect to David, do note that the predominant historiographical perspective in the modern day is that the tribe of Judah was actually among the Palestinians (better said, Canaanites) of the time, and that they followed what was basically a Yahwahist heresy that denied the reality of the polytheistic pantheon, a bit like Akhenaten had done in Egypt. The Biblical claims of a captivity in Egypt and descent from Sumer would basically have been political propaganda intended to give the new religion a cosmopolitan legitimacy, and also to smear an enemy in the case of Egypt.

Though that very propaganda was, of course, an attempt at nation-building.

More about the hypothesized evolution of Yahweh into a monotheistic deity, possibly from El or possibly separately

Let me break the terms down:

'Nation' is a term applies to people(s). It's a modern extension of the ancient concept of a 'tribe' or 'clan': people who are loosely and generally related by heritage, religion, culture, language, or other common identity features.
'State' is a term that applies to administration(s). It's a modern extension of the ancient concept of 'kingdom' or 'empire', where one group controls and administers a territory, including all of the disparate people(s) that live within it. Historically kingdoms (not to mention empires) were not too concerned with who lived within their borders, so long as those people(s) paid their taxes, obeyed edicts, and kept their noses clean.
'Country' is a term that applies to land. It's an identification with a region that one resides in, a modern extension of the ancient concept of the agricultural city-state. At heart, 'country' refers to the place we live, work, have friends, make families, all delimited by the our limitations in daily travel.

The problem with these terms is that they were much more aligned in the ancient world. Agricultural and pastoral tribes lived in given regions and didn't move around that much, so country and nation were more-or-less conjoined, and while there might be remote administration from a king or empire, that generally didn't have a huge effect on normal people's lives. Does a farming village in Iberia really care whether they are giving their tithe to a Roman Emperor or a Gaulish King? This started to change a bit with the introduction of large-scale monotheistic religion, which unified peoples broadly, but the real kicker was advances in transportation technology starting in the early Colonial era. Administrations began to project power faster and wider; people(s) dispersed, expanded their range, and intermingled with far away peoples; people's conception of homeland expanded from what one can reach in a day on foot or by horse to what one can reach in a day by ship or (eventually) rail.  All of this expansion and intermingling created a bit of a panic among both administrative entities and the (tribal) leadership of people(s), who wanted to define more clearly who and what they had control over. So the concepts of 'state' and 'nation' came into being. Rather than having (say) a Frankish king who basically ruled over whatever people happened to live in the territory the king's military managed to control, the concept of 'France' was reified to refer to a given territory, the people in that territory were reified as 'French' no matter who they were, and the king became the administrative head of France's state. This allowed European states to expand colonially into far-flung regions while maintaining a core identity. The nation-state was invented to unify people, state, and country in a world where they were rapidly disintegrating due to sheer mobility.
The next development, of course, was nationalism: an effort to recreate primitive tribalism within the modern administrative state. People who talk about the nation-state in that mode are quite dangerous. But that's a different topic…

Now our homeland is whatever we can reach in 90 minutes from the ISS. I wonder how long it will be until it is anything light can reach in 30 minutes?

@ScottRowe 90 minutes ... unless you take a Boeing ;-) https://news.sky.com/story/two-astronauts-left-behind-on-iss-as-troubled-boeing-starliner-capsule-lands-on-earth-empty-13210886

I pretty have the same conception (nationalism as it is today grow slowly out of an already existing reality), and believe your answer is quite well written, but a limit in this answer is that it is either too under-specific ("All of this expansion and intermingling created a bit of a panic among both administrative entities" where, when, who?), either too focus on the French, when my question is, it seems to me, also oriented towards other time and place


But I have most difficulties in believing that the local "peoples" did not in some way or another identify with the Kingdom or Empire which ruled their territory.

The issue here is for how such people could identify which king or emperor ruled their territory. If you live in some house between the castle of some Charles the 32nd in the east and some Henry the 44th in the west, with whom of both do you personally "identify"?
Sometimes people lived nearby their rule, spoke the same language and held the same religion as their ruler, and different language and religion than any other nearby ruler. Sometimes neither of those. Sometimes the rulers redivided lands, such that during a given week, one might change rulers 3 times (known to some of the ruled only months later).
So identifying with some government was fickle without stable borders. Of course within stable bordes such as from islands or city walls, stronger psychological ties were typical. But until recently, the world population lived by majority in rural areas of large landmasses, not cities or small islands. Even today it's only the most developed countries which have more city dwellers than rural population.
And so for the peasants before nations, there is not much identification with anything before nations. They just pay taxes to their lord, and receive news every couple of months informing them about which king their lord is currently sworn to, which typically does not change much as the main governance received is by that local lord, not some faraway (geographically and legally) king.
Every now and then a peasant might be called upon to fight in an army. So they go to battle shouting "For Henry!" But the next day their lord changes allegiance, and so the next day the same peasant will fight shouting "For Charles!". There is not much in the way of identifying with some king in all that.
People would identify with their region and religion often, but with large migrations and invasions this was also not always that stable or useful, and could be in conflict with by whome one was governed.
Note that of course for some people there were also long periods of stability with the same ruling dynasty, the same prevailing religion and culture, the same language and so on. But this was circumstantial, not institutional stability.

Yes, prior to modern Europe there were no nations.
Nations came into existence after the nation states were created. Nation states were a product of the Treaty of Westphalia, which ended the 30 years war in 1648. It gave us this modern system of countries with clearly defined borders and pretty colors on the map. Each country got it's official language, flag, anthem etc etc.
Nation is an artificial concept, and it is more general (includes a larger number of people) than ethnicity. Sometimes borders of nation states and ethnicities coincided nicely, like in Denmark and Portugal, and sometimes they did not like in France or Germany. For example, Elsace-Lorraine is predominantly German ethnically, and yet it went over to France after WW1, and Das Fuhrer used that fact as one of the motives to start a new war.
Shakespeare and Machiavelli saw the nation states just as they were emerging and coming into power, and were fascinated by this new never before seen phenomenon.
Nation states are more than just pretty colors on the map, they gave rise to a whole new way of systematising violence (prisons, war, military ranks, terms of service), gave rise to modern empirical science, produced nationalism (which I would argue is currently at it's strongest in Poland as far as Europe is concerned) and changed the economic relations.
Johann Fichte liked the whole idea of the nation state.

Except that 'nation' also has a 3000 year old provenance.  I wouldnt bring it up but for the fact that one of the current (Westphalian) states claims a d.i.r.e.c.t lineage from that  other 3000 year old concept

this article you provided talks about goys, which is a very controversial term from the ancient hebrew language, and nation is a rather inaccurate translation, and it definitely has nothing to do with nation states in the treaty of westphalia sense. that term could also have been translated as tribes / peoples / clans / ethnicities

I'd say a country is more or less just the geographical plot of land, engulfed by political or natural borders. Which often also serves as a shorthand for what goes on within those borders.
A state is usually defined as a governing entity involving a government a piece of occupied land and a population of that land that is subject to that government.
While a nation is a dedicated group of people, which sees itself as a collective and not just as a collection of people.
And a nation-state is when the political structure of a state is implemented by one nation. This kind of "nationalism" usually takes 2 forms, one is the independence movement of a particular group which hence become a nation of their own and demand sovereign rule over themselves. And the other is if a state tries to unify it's various subcultures into a collective whole usually to avoid them falling apart and forming smaller nations-states of their own or because that larger empire is seen as beneficial by whomever wants it to remain or form.
I guess the problem is that while the a nation could theoretically exist without a state, the concept of a nation likely originated with a the idea of a nation-state, so it's probably tricky to apply the label to nation like structure, such as idk clans, large families, tribes, language groups, cultural groups, ethnic groups or any other sort of group.
Where many of those would fit the definition of a nation as given above and could form a nation state if they took control over a country and formed a state, but which would not otherwise be considered a nation prior to doing so.
The other thing is that you'd probably discriminate by size and power. So while a family of 4 might have a country, a government and a population you'd hardly call them a state. Of course they wouldn't be a sovereign state anyway as they are subject to the laws of the country surrounding their land, but they might nonetheless theoretically count as state.
Which hints at the other problem that "state" itself is lousily defined, mostly by those already considering themselves as states, which can make or break a new state by accepting a new state or not.
So while rarely stated, it probably has a lot to do with power, size and significance regardless of whether all the other elements apply.
The other thing is that for a country to be synonymous with a nation or a state, you'd need to settle there. A roaming tribe might be a nation, but they are not a state and don't claim permanent possessing to a country.
Likewise people roaming mixing and mingling both takes culture, language and whatnot to a larger area, but also always creates local cultures, languages, groupings and whatnot which could take forms of opponents or allies.
Similar when boundaries of countries constantly change through warfare or whatnot. Like in Europe you could be catholic one day and protestant the other simply by means of your ruler changing or changing their religion. So your own personal philosophy might not have mattered. So it was much more common to be displaced and adapting to a local culture or moving through different cultures than it was to have a universal and lasting culture of a particular empire.
Or even if that existed people weren't always generally educated, couldn't read or write the language anyway. Like the catholic church was using Latin a lot while that was literally a dead language I once heard from a priest that "hocus pocus" apparently meant "Hoc corpus" or stuff like that, so there could very well be a disconnect between the culture of the rulers and the culture of the ruled and often enough grand narratives of us vs them of "the state" as the exploiter and stealing entity formed. At other times the king might have gotten legitimacy by utility of protection while at other times they might have taken control with fear and occupation (farmers can't just run from their land).
So especially with political power resting firmly in the hands of the church and the aristocracy there might not have been much of a sense of loyalty the more and collectivity the more you approach the fringes of power which very well could include majorities of people. Like sure some commoners could become knights, but "knight" means you own a horse and you have to be plenty rich to do that...
Also towns were a lot smaller, so the ability of people to even know people outside of the perimeter of their own plots of land, villages or maybe the next city were quite limited so the ability to form coherent "nations" that went beyond the family and the village were also quite limited. Not to mention that language wise they might have all spoken slightly different languages. Again with a developed high language that serves as lingua franca things get a little easier to communicate but for that you'd need time and continuity of some sort.
So while there were probably plenty of examples of proto-nations, you might argue that what we consider know as nations (with the respective sizes and scopes) would need certain requirements to come together which made that concept flourish with the rather recent development of the nation state.
Though obviously the attempts of imperial rulers to "unify" the tribes could also already be described as attempts at nationalism if you would wanted to define them by that route. So usually one rather looks at the emergence of groups voting for self-determination as a group rather than the attempts to create a group to solidify an empire.

The oldest references to 'nation' seem to be from a certain 3000 year old book
Genesis

I will make you into a great nation, and I will bless you; I will make your name great, and you will be a blessing.
12:2


As for me, this is my covenant with you: You will be the father of many nations. No longer will you be called Abram; your name will be Abraham, for I have made you a father of many nations.
17:4-5


From these the maritime peoples spread out into their territories by their clans within their nations, each with its own language.
10:5

Exodus

Now if you obey me fully and keep my covenant, then out of all nations you will be my treasured possession. Although the whole earth is mine, you will be for me a kingdom of priests and a holy nation.
19:5-6


If you are pleased with me, teach me your ways so I may know you and continue to find favor with you. Remember that this nation is your people.
33:13


I will drive out nations before you and enlarge your territory, and no one will covet your land when you go up three times each year to appear before the Lord your God.
34:24


I'm no scholar or ancient Hebrew or Greek, but KJV isn't that old and I'm not sure the word "nation" was used in previous translations or not. it makes sense to me that modern Protestants have come to use the term "people group" as a closer approximation of what would have been meant in the original. "Linguistic community" would probably be more precise.

@BrianZ "people group" sounds like something from Thing Explainer.

@BrianZ See my comment above to Dennis

@ScottRowe Playing polysemy games is not decent behavior. But when one nation (Westphalian) kills a large number of a(nother) "people group" on the basis that its a nation (mythological) that game is already in full swing and we would do well to note it
